# Javascript: How do I fetch all of the resources from an endpoint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, browser, karma-runner

I am using Karma and Mocha for running integration tests on my codebase. For validating the codebase in Node.js, I have a folder of test cases.

```
repository/
├── test/
│   ├── cases/
│   │   ├── case1.json
│   │   ├── case2.json
│   │   ├── case3.json
│   │   └── case4.json
│   ├── browser/
│   │   └── testFactory.spec.ts
│   └── node/
        └── testFactory.spec.ts
```

For my Node.js tests, I just use `fs.readdirSync(testCaseFolder, "utf-8")` to get the filenames of all the test cases, and then loop through them.

```
for (const filename of filenames) {
  const data = fs.readFileSync(testCaseFolder + filename, "utf-8");
  const testCase: ModelTestCase = JSON.parse(data.toString());
  const testName = getTestName(filename);
  describe(testName, function() {
    it(getTestDescription(filename), async function() {
      /* do some testing here */
    });
  });
}
```

Now I need to rewrite this testing design to work in the browser for testing via Karma. Karma has a way to specify a path to static files that can be served up during testing in the configuration: [Karma - Files](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/files.html). So in this case I added to my Karma Configuration:

```json
files: [
  {pattern: 'test/cases/*.json', watched: false, included: false, served: true, nocache: false}
],
```

and set up a proxy to serve the test cases endpoint at a convenient URL:

```json
proxies: {
  "/cases/": "http://localhost:8080/base/test/cases/"
},
```

Now I could theoretically access test case 1 with the following code:

```
fetch("/cases/case1.json");
```

How can I write a loop to fetch every test case located in the `/cases/` endpoint that is browser compatible JavaScript?

Comment: are you keeping test cases in the `/cases/` directory that are not browser compatable?

Comment: all the cases are browser compatible test cases. So I want to run all of them, just in a browser environment. The cases each look like a json file with a description, input, and expected output,